# Very large $sum and $average value in Mongo Aggregate doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing an average and a sum of items using Mongo Aggregate

```
pipeline = [
    {$match: {///conditions here}},
    {$group: {_id: 'type', 'total': {'$sum':'$duration'}, 'avg': {'$sum':'$duration'}}},
  ]
```

The aggregate function works, however for $sum and $avg results sometimes I get negative values. The issue is that $duration in the database are large integers.

How should I make it work on these large values?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/13995143/988078

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by coercing your NumberLong values into floats before trying to sum them by adding a floating point 0 to them in a `$project` like this:

```js
pipeline = [
    {$match: {///conditions here}},
    {$project: {type: 1, duration: {$add: ['$duration', 0.0]}}},
    {$group: {_id: 'type', 'total': {'$sum':'$duration'}, 'avg': {'$sum':'$duration'}}},
]
```